# Cat and awk Commands

Tags: awk, syslinux, cat

What does these commands mean in linux? GBPUSD30MIN and USDJPY30MIN are text files with data having 4 columns and 1000 rows.

```
cat GBPUSD30MIN | awk '{ print NF }' | uniq -c

awk '{ print $4}' USDJPY30MIN  >USDJPY
```

Comment: The first command prints a list of *number of fields* for lines in the GBP file... kinda. It prints 2 columns: first the number of consecutive lines, second the field count. That output, I'm guessing, is not particularly useful for you. One way to experiment is to execute the pipline piece by piece: `cat file` should be obvious; `cat file | awk '{print NF}'` is a bit more interesting. I suspect you really want `cat file | awk '{print $NF}'`

Comment: the second command copies the 4th column from the 30MIN file

Comment: You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info to learn  more about awk

Comment: Note that `cat` is unnecessary here. `awk` allows taking filenames to read as positional parameter, which is what  you see in the second command.